# How should I design this in auto layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have this view:

[image: AL View]

It basically consists of the 4 groups I have named.  Groups A & B should naturally be at the top of the view.  So I have anchored them to the top.

> In Group A, both labels are anchored to the top and left by leading
>   and topspaces to superview.
>
> In Group B, the top image and label are anchored to the top right and
>   then the other 2 images and 2 labels are anchored to the THEM, so they
>   move together.
>
> In Group C, the lowest label is anchored to the bottom and the others
>   to IT, so they all move together.

What should I do with Group D?  I want it to remain in the center of the view, vertically speaking.  Basically I want the content to fit the screen vertically because in iPhone 5, there is a lot of empty space between Group D and Group C, which I understand why.  What I want to visualize is what would be the best way to make it always cover the screen vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a container view, pinning the vertical center to the superview's vertical center. Put your subviews inside that, with vertical constraints between them and between the top subview and the top of the container view, and the bottom subview and the bottom of the container view.

Container views make a lot of Autolayout problems much simpler.

Comment: is there a way to select all desired controls and embed in a new view automatically? I ask because I know when I drag a uiview or uicontainer view into the scene, itll break EVERYTHING else :)

Comment: Don't know, sorry, I haven't done anything in interface builder for a while.

Comment: Just as an extra tidbit, there is an Embed in View option in the Editor Menu which allows you to select multiple items and automatically embed them!  THANK YOU XCODE!